# To print tables from web pages in structured order using pandas in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i am trying to print the table in structured format using pandas
my code:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(url,header = 0)
for df in dfs:
    print(dfs)
```

the url is a wiki page
for example

```
0  name age tick
1  aaa  22   s
2  sss  11   e
```

but am getting as

```
0 name
1  aaa
2  sss
age
22
11
```

like vertically
plz help

Comment: Please provide the HTML example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation on set_option http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html. Try to fiddle around with these:

```
pd.set_option('display.height', 1000) 
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```